# MySQL Order by + Group by drastically slow down the query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have the following query that, despite its complexity, performs well in the following shape:

```
SELECT 

`listings`.*, 
`auth_agents`.*, 
`symbols`.`code` AS `symbol_code`,
`symbols`.`text` AS `symbol_text`,
`symbols`.`position` AS `symbol_position`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(`categories_countries`.`translation`, `c`.`name`) ORDER BY CASE WHEN `c`.`category_id` = 106 THEN 1 ELSE `c`.`category_id` END) as `category_names`,
`pv_1`.`value` AS `transaction_type_name`,
`pv_2`.`value` AS `property_type_name`,
`listings_statuses`.`name` AS `status`,
CONCAT(`pv_3`.`value`, 'property/', `listings`.`slug`, '/', `listings`.`listing_id`) AS `url`,
price_range(`listings`.`price_sales_min`, `listings`.`price_sales`, `symbols`.`code`, `symbols`.`position`, `listings`.`listings_price_qualifier_id`) AS `price_sales_range`,
price_range(`listings`.`price_lettings_min`, `listings`.`price_lettings`, `symbols`.`code`, `symbols`.`position`, `listings`.`listings_price_qualifier_id`) AS `price_lettings_range`,
summary(`listings`.`description`, `listings`.`summary`) AS `summary`,
short_title(`categories`.`name`, `categories`.`title`, `pv_1`.`value`, `listings`.`city`, `listings`.`region`, `listings`.`area`) AS `short_title`,
IF(`listings`.`listings_price_qualifier_id` = 2, TRUE, FALSE) AS `POA`,
IF((SELECT `listings_categories`.`listing_id` FROM `listings_categories` WHERE `listings_categories`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id` AND `listings_categories`.`category_id` = 124 LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL, TRUE, FALSE) AS `serviced_office`,

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('|', `auth_agents_staff`.`auth_agents_staff_id`, `auth_staff`.`f_name`, `auth_staff`.`l_name`, `auth_staff`.`photo`)) AS `agents_staff`,
(SELECT CONCAT('http://cdn.commercialpeople.com/images/', `listings`.`auth_agent_id`, '/', `listings_media`.`filename`) FROM `listings_media` WHERE `listings_media`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id` ORDER BY `default` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `image`,
(SELECT COUNT(`listings_media`.`listings_media_id`) FROM `listings_media` WHERE `listings_media`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id` AND `listings_media`.`listings_media_type_id` = 1) AS `image_count`,
(SELECT COUNT(`listings_media`.`listings_media_id`) FROM `listings_media` WHERE `listings_media`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id` AND `listings_media`.`listings_media_type_id` = 3) AS `pdf_count`,
(SELECT COUNT(`listings_media`.`listings_media_id`) FROM `listings_media` WHERE `listings_media`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id` AND `listings_media`.`listings_media_type_id` = 4) AS `floor_plan_count`,


distance(`listings`.`lat`, `listings`.`lng`, 51.5073500, -0.1277600) AS `distance` 

FROM `listings` 
JOIN `listings_coords` ON `listings_coords`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id` 

JOIN `auth_agents` ON `listings`.`auth_agent_id` = `auth_agents`.`auth_agent_id` 
JOIN `branches` USING (`branch_id`) 
LEFT JOIN `listings_auth_agents_staff` ON `listings_auth_agents_staff`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id` 
LEFT JOIN `auth_agents_staff` ON `listings_auth_agents_staff`.`listing_id` IS NOT NULL AND `listings_auth_agents_staff`.`auth_agents_staff_id` = `auth_agents_staff`.`auth_agents_staff_id` 
LEFT JOIN `auth` AS `auth_staff` ON `listings_auth_agents_staff`.`listing_id` IS NOT NULL AND `auth_agents_staff`.`auth_agents_staff_id` IS NOT NULL AND 
`auth_staff`.`auth_id` = `auth_agents_staff`.`auth_id` 

JOIN `parameters_values` AS `pv_1` 
ON `pv_1`.`parameter_id` = 2 AND `pv_1`.`country_id` = 223 AND `pv_1`.`key` = `listings`.`transaction_type` 

JOIN `parameters_values` AS `pv_2` 
ON `pv_2`.`parameter_id` = 1 AND `pv_2`.`country_id` = 223 AND `pv_2`.`key` = `listings`.`property_type` 

JOIN `parameters_values` AS `pv_3` 
ON `pv_3`.`parameter_id` = 5 AND `pv_2`.`country_id` = 223 

JOIN `countries` ON `listings`.`country_id` = `countries`.`country_id` 
JOIN `countries_symbols` ON `countries`.`country_id` = `countries_symbols`.`country_id` 
JOIN `symbols` ON `countries_symbols`.`symbol_id` = `symbols`.`symbol_id` 

JOIN `listings_units` ON `listings`.`listings_unit_id` = `listings_units`.`listings_unit_id` 

JOIN `listings_units` AS `user_units` ON `user_units`.`listings_unit_id` = 2 


JOIN `listings_statuses` ON `listings`.`listings_status_id` = `listings_statuses`.`listings_status_id` 
LEFT JOIN `listings_statuses_countries` ON `listings_statuses`.`listings_status_id` = `listings_statuses_countries`.`listings_status_id` 
AND `listings_statuses_countries`.`country_id` = '223' 

JOIN `listings_categories` ON `listings_categories`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id`  
JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`category_id` = `listings_categories`.`category_id` 

JOIN `listings_categories` AS `lc` ON `lc`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id`  
JOIN `categories` AS `c` ON `c`.`category_id` = `lc`.`category_id` 
LEFT JOIN `categories_countries` ON `c`.`category_id` = `categories_countries`.`category_id` AND `categories_countries`.`country_id` = '223' 

LEFT JOIN `listings_lettings`  
ON (`listings`.`transaction_type` = 2 OR `listings`.`transaction_type` = 3) AND `listings_lettings`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id` 
LEFT JOIN `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies`  
ON (`listings`.`transaction_type` = 2 OR `listings`.`transaction_type` = 3) AND `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies`.`listings_lettings_rent_frequency_id` = `listings_lettings`.`listings_lettings_rent_frequency_id` 

LEFT JOIN `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies` AS `llrf` ON `llrf`.`listings_lettings_rent_frequency_id` = 2 
WHERE `listings`.`active` = 1 AND `listings`.`published_flag` = 1 AND 
`listings`.`listings_status_id` = 1 AND
`listings`.`lat` BETWEEN 51.333436956522 AND 51.681263043478 AND 
`listings`.`lng` BETWEEN -0.40717687879372 AND 0.15165687879372 AND 
st_within(`listings_coords`.`coords`, @poly) AND 

IF (`listings`.`transaction_type` = 2 || `listings`.`transaction_type` = 3, 
`listings`.`price_lettings` * `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies`.`months` >= `llrf`.`months` * 500,
TRUE
) AND 
IF(`listings_units`.`meters` IS NULL, TRUE, `listings`.`max_size` * `listings_units`.`meters` >= 100 * `user_units`.`meters`) AND 
`listings`.`country_id` = 223 

GROUP BY `listings`.`listing_id`  
ORDER BY `listings`.`created_at` 
LIMIT 10;
```

As you can see, the first query grabs the polygon which then is used in polygon search through spatial function. The query executes in aprox 0.06sec.

However adding any ORDER BY clause results in a drastic performance drop and ends up executing in 17 seconds.

Now - I've done some research and I know this might be to do with either clustered indexes or just adding the right indexing in general, but after hours spent trying to either return just the ID's and then run another query to get the data or simply getting rid of the GROUP BY and removing the joins (which seemed to have worked at first but then another performance issues appeared when I joined a few tables to do a price search) - I gave up.

I tried to run a query without grouping and then group the results, like:

```
SELECT * FROM ( *the query* ) AS results GROUP BY listing_id
```

But I got pretty much the same results.

Is there a way to optimise the query so I could do both grouping and sorting?

Here is the EXPLAIN:

```
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | countries                          | const  | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | const                                                            |    1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort                              |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | user_units                         | const  | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | const                                                            |    1 | NULL                                                                      |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | listings_statuses                  | const  | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | const                                                            |    1 | NULL                                                                      |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | listings_statuses_countries        | const  | PRIMARY,country_id                                                                | PRIMARY                              | 8       | const,const                                                      |    1 | Using index                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | countries_symbols                  | ref    | PRIMARY,symbol_id                                                                 | PRIMARY                              | 4       | const                                                            |    1 | Using index                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | symbols                            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.countries_symbols.symbol_id                           |    1 | NULL                                                                      |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | pv_2                               | ref    | parameter_id,country_id                                                           | parameter_id                         | 8       | const,const                                                      |    2 | NULL                                                                      |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | pv_1                               | ref    | parameter_id,country_id                                                           | parameter_id                         | 8       | const,const                                                      |    3 | NULL                                                                      |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | pv_3                               | ref    | parameter_id                                                                      | parameter_id                         | 4       | const                                                            |    4 | NULL                                                                      |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | listings                           | range  | SEE BELOW                                                                         | compound                             | 20      | NULL                                                             | 2594 | Using index condition; Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | listings_units                     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.listings.listings_unit_id                             |    1 | Using where                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | listings_coords                    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,coords                                                                    | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.listings.listing_id                                   |    1 | Using where                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | auth_agents                        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.listings.auth_agent_id                                |    1 | NULL                                                                      |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | branches                           | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.listings.branch_id                                    |    1 | Using index                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | listings_categories                | ref    | PRIMARY,listings_categories_category_id_foreign                                   | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.listings.listing_id                                   |    1 | Using index                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | lc                                 | ref    | PRIMARY,listings_categories_category_id_foreign                                   | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.listings.listing_id                                   |    1 | Using index                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | listings_auth_agents_staff         | ref    | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.listings.listing_id                                   |    1 | Using index                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | categories                         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.listings_categories.category_id                       |    1 | NULL                                                                      |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | c                                  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.lc.category_id                                        |    1 | NULL                                                                      |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | auth_agents_staff                  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.listings_auth_agents_staff.auth_agents_staff_id       |    1 | Using where                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | auth_staff                         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                           | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.auth_agents_staff.auth_id                             |    1 | Using where                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | categories_countries               | eq_ref | PRIMARY,categories_countries_country_id_foreign                                   | PRIMARY                              | 8       | cp_staging.lc.category_id,const                                  |    1 | NULL                                                                      |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | listings_lettings                  | ref    | listings_lettings_listing_id_foreign                                              | listings_lettings_listing_id_foreign | 4       | cp_staging.listings.listing_id                                   |    1 | Using where                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | listings_lettings_rent_frequencies | eq_ref | PRIMARY,listings_lettings_rent_frequencies_id_months                              | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp_staging.listings_lettings.listings_lettings_rent_frequency_id |    1 | Using where                                                               |
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | llrf                               | const  | PRIMARY,listings_lettings_rent_frequencies_id_months                              | PRIMARY                              | 4       | const                                                            |    1 | Using where                                                               |
    |  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | listings_media                     | ref    | listings_media_listing_id_foreign,listings_media_listings_media_type_id_foreign   | listings_media_listing_id_foreign    | 4       | func                                                             |    1 | Using where                                                               |
    |  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | listings_media                     | ref    | listings_media_listing_id_foreign,listings_media_listings_media_type_id_foreign   | listings_media_listing_id_foreign    | 4       | func                                                             |    1 | Using where                                                               |
    |  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | listings_media                     | ref    | listings_media_listing_id_foreign,listings_media_listings_media_type_id_foreign   | listings_media_listing_id_foreign    | 4       | func                                                             |    1 | Using where                                                               |
    |  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | listings_categories                | eq_ref | PRIMARY,listings_categories_category_id_foreign                                   | PRIMARY                              | 8       | func,const                                                       |    1 | Using index                                                               |
```

5th column value for `listings` table (pulled out so that format of above table could be preserved)    `PRIMARY,listings_former_id_unique,listings_price_sales_index,listings_price_sales_min_index,listings_price_lettings_index,listings_price_lettings_min_index,listings_country_id_foreign,listings_agent_id_foreign,listings_listings_status_id_foreign,listings_listings_price_qualifier_id_foreign,listings_listings_unit_id_foreign,listings_listings_tenure_type_id_foreign,agents_staff_id,listings_listings_class_id_foreign_idx,listings_listings_location_type_id_foreign_idx,listings_listings_branch_id_foreign_idx,latlng,listings_city,listings_created_at,listings_country_created_at,listings_transaction_type,listings_listing_id_transaction_type,listings_listings_coords_id,listings_created_at_listing_id,compound`

Comment: Step 1 - replace select * with selecting just the fields you need.  Then, since you are not selecting any aggregates, replace the group by with a select distinct

Comment: oh just in case - had to strip out half the select fields, but I do use aggregate functions (ie GROUP_CONCAT) - hence the LEFT JOINs)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE listings`. It would be best if you can provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all tables involved, in fact. Also, please edit the full, unaltered query back in. This problem is complicated enough without information being hidden, and yes, what you are selecting is important to know, in terms of performance.

Comment: Not good to have that many indexes on `listings`.  Many will never be used, especially those involving 'flags'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all the tables except `listings`, `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies`, `llrf`, `listings_units`.
2. let's optimize that query.  Keep the GROUP BY, ORDER BY and LIMIT and only some of the WHERE.
3. See if that gives you the desired 10 `listing_ids`.

If we can get that query to work reasonably fast, then do

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( the above query as a subquery ) x
    JOIN ... -- the rest of the JOINs, using x.listings_id where needed
GROUP BY x.listing_id   -- just in case
ORDER BY x.created_at;  -- repeated
```

Comment: I added all the selected fields. I'm about to do the search for just the IDs, with only the necessary tables and WHEREs, will post soon.

Answer (score 0):

I've left out all the the optional bits (also removed GROUP BY as it was then unnecessary), it pretty much comes down to:

```
SET @poly = (SELECT `polygon` FROM locations WHERE location_id = 65);

SELECT

`listings`.`listing_id`

FROM `listings`
JOIN `listings_coords` ON `listings_coords`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id`
JOIN `listings_units` ON `listings`.`listings_unit_id` = `listings_units`.`listings_unit_id`
JOIN `listings_units` AS `user_units` ON `user_units`.`listings_unit_id` = 2

LEFT JOIN `listings_lettings`
ON (`listings`.`transaction_type` = 2 OR `listings`.`transaction_type` = 3) AND `listings_lettings`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`listing_id`
LEFT JOIN `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies`
ON (`listings`.`transaction_type` = 2 OR `listings`.`transaction_type` = 3) AND `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies`.`listings_lettings_rent_frequency_id` = `listings_lettings`.`listings_lettings_rent_frequency_id`

LEFT JOIN `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies` AS `llrf` ON `llrf`.`listings_lettings_rent_frequency_id` = 2
WHERE
`listings`.`lat` BETWEEN 51.333436956522 AND 51.681263043478 AND
`listings`.`lng` BETWEEN -0.40717687879372 AND 0.15165687879372 AND
st_within(`listings_coords`.`coords`, @poly) AND

(
    `listings`.`transaction_type` = 1  OR
    `listings`.`price_lettings` * `listings_lettings_rent_frequencies`.`months` >= `llrf`.`months` * 500

)
AND
(
    `listings_units`.`meters` IS NULL OR
    `listings`.`max_size` * `listings_units`.`meters` >= 100 * `user_units`.`meters`
)
AND
`listings`.`country_id` = 223

ORDER BY `listings`.`created_at`
LIMIT 10;
```

It seems that it's no the ORDER BY clause now that slows it down. Current explain:

```
+----+-------------+------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                              | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                                         | key                                  | key_len | ref                                                      | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_units                         | const  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | PRIMARY                              | 4       | const                                                    |    1 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | listings                           | range  | PRIMARY,listings_country_id_foreign,listings_listings_unit_id_foreign,latlng,listings_country_created_at,listings_country_units_created_at,listings_transaction_type,listings_listing_id_transaction_type,listings_lat_lng_created_at | latlng                               | 10      | NULL                                                     | 3728 | Using index condition; Using where                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | listings_coords                    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,coords                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp.listings.listing_id                                   |    1 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | listings_lettings                  | ref    | listings_lettings_listing_id_foreign                                                                                                                                                                                                  | listings_lettings_listing_id_foreign | 4       | cp.listings.listing_id                                   |    1 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | listings_lettings_rent_frequencies | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | PRIMARY                              | 4       | cp.listings_lettings.listings_lettings_rent_frequency_id |    1 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | listings_units                     | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | NULL                                 | NULL    | NULL                                                     |    6 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | llrf                               | const  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | PRIMARY                              | 4       | const                                                    |    1 | Using where                                        |
+----+-------------+------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Removing the price and size conditions results in better performance and search without filesort. It might be to do with bad indexing, although as pointed out - I do have quite a few of those indexes. Current performance of the above query is aprox 5s. Also removing st_within function seems to resolve the issue (0.047s). As you said - I can easily perform the initial search in the subquery, get the desired 10 IDs and carry on with the JOINs in the outer query.

This is the create statement for listings table:

```
CREATE TABLE `listings` (
  `listing_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `auth_agent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `branch_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `listings_status_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `listings_price_qualifier_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `listings_tenure_type_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `listings_class_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `listings_location_type_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_type` enum('1','2','3') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `auth_agents_staff_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `published_flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `address_1` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_2` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` char(150) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `postcode` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `hide_address` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `street_view` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `lat` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `lng` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `price_sales` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_sales_min` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_lettings` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_lettings_min` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_per_unit_sales` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_per_unit_lettings` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_size` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_size` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `listings_unit_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `summary` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `short_title` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `agent_ref` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `former_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`listing_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `listings_transaction_listing_id` (`transaction_type`,`listing_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `listings_former_id_unique` (`former_id`),
  KEY `listings_price_sales_index` (`price_sales`),
  KEY `listings_price_sales_min_index` (`price_sales_min`),
  KEY `listings_price_lettings_index` (`price_lettings`),
  KEY `listings_price_lettings_min_index` (`price_lettings_min`),
  KEY `listings_country_id_foreign` (`country_id`),
  KEY `listings_agent_id_foreign` (`auth_agent_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_status_id_foreign` (`listings_status_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_price_qualifier_id_foreign` (`listings_price_qualifier_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_unit_id_foreign` (`listings_unit_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_tenure_type_id_foreign` (`listings_tenure_type_id`),
  KEY `agents_staff_id` (`auth_agents_staff_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_class_id_foreign_idx` (`listings_class_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_location_type_id_foreign_idx` (`listings_location_type_id`),
  KEY `listings_listings_branch_id_foreign_idx` (`branch_id`),
  KEY `lat_lng_country_id_active_published` (`lat`,`lng`,`country_id`,`active`,`published_flag`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_agent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`auth_agent_id`) REFERENCES `auth_agents` (`auth_agent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_country_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`country_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`auth_agents_staff_id`) REFERENCES `agents_staff` (`agents_staff_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_branch_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`branch_id`) REFERENCES `branches` (`branch_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_class_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_class_id`) REFERENCES `listings_classes` (`listings_class_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_location_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_location_type_id`) REFERENCES `listings_location_types` (`listings_location_type_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_price_qualifier_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_price_qualifier_id`) REFERENCES `listings_price_qualifiers` (`listings_price_qualifier_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_status_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_status_id`) REFERENCES `listings_statuses` (`listings_status_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_tenure_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_tenure_type_id`) REFERENCES `listings_tenure_types` (`listings_tenure_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `listings_listings_unit_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`listings_unit_id`) REFERENCES `listings_units` (`listings_unit_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34832 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```